# navigation bar which contains a link which redirect to a frame in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

```
<div class='nav'>
    <ul>
        {% for li in th_coun_li %}
        <li><a href="#" onclick=Myfunction({{li}})>Thread Dump {{li}}</a></li><br> 
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="frame"></div>

<script>
    function Myfunction(li){
        src1="<iframe src='{% url 'threadcount1' li %}' width='2000' height='1000';></iframe>";
        document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML = src1 ;
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to make a nav bar when that nav bar links are clicked then it will open an i frame but it is giving me this error:

```
Reverse for 'threadcount1' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1               
pattern(s) tried: ['mainpage/analysis/threadcount/(?P<th>[0-9]+)$']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass in your js variable like that. Try changing the way you pass your data. Considering you have a trailing forward slash (i.e. `/`) in your url.

Change this:

```
function Myfunction(li){
    src1="<iframe src='{% url 'threadcount1' li %}' width='2000' height='1000';></iframe>";
    document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML = src1 ;
}
```

To this:

```
function Myfunction(li){
    src1 = "<iframe src='{% url 'threadcount1' %}" + li + "' width='2000' height='1000';></iframe>";
    document.getElementById('frame').innerHTML = src1 ;
}
```